# Advice for a Counting Widget in Java

Tags: java, widget

So I'm currently learning java and want to make a widget to make my desk job easier. I have to keep track of how much of each task I get done and turn that in at the end of the day, so I want to make a widget with multiple categories and a button to add and a button to decrease count by one. I know this is simple easy crap but I dont really know where to start. I know concepts like loops, objects, classes etc I just don't know how to connect it together. Any advice?

Comment: Try another website. SO is for specific questions, like if you tried some stuff and were stuck.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Your question as it stands is probably too broad, and will likely get closed... Check out the tour for what sorts of questions are likely to be well received (http://stackoverflow.com/tour).  That said, I recommend trying out the GUI tutorial trail at oracle: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/

Answer (score 0):

I googled 'make a java desktop widgit'... I found the following [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IFIlr6cpX64) video that I think will be helpful.

Depending on where you are in your Java programming journey: 
The first thing you need would be an IDE (Netbeans, Eclipse, IntelliJ)

Then [JRE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html) and JDK 
(www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)

Then you should be set to start programming